# Pass API Text Data to other Page Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm facing an issue regarding API datas,
I want the pass the texts, Image generated by API to another screen screen

Here is the

```
      String _name(dynamic user){
    return user['name']['title'];

  }
 String _description(dynamic user){
    return user['name']['description'];
  }
```

I want to pass these texts to the next screen using Provider or MaterialRoute Page,
How can I do so in a real example

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by 2 ways:

1. Pass a data to screen as arguments. For example:

```dart
class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String description;

  SecondScreen(this.title, this.description);
}
```

And in routing:

```dart
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen(title, description)),
);
```

2. Create a model class in Provider and add data to it before moving to another screen and access this data in the second screen.

A Provider basically allows you to access data belonging to class from any widget. [Here](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) is a link to the Provider package. You'll find examples over there.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but how do it index "title" and description knowing that they are all Text("_name(snapshot.data[index]"), how can I add title or decription key to it.
Thank you

Comment: Can you update your code in the question?